# How to eliminate unnecessary page break in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have couple of lines (text) followed by table. I want both the text and table to appear in same page, now text appears in one page and table in next page. How to change it? I have tried using `\vspace{-5cm}`but of no use, is there a better way?

Example:

```
\chapter{bbbb : aaaa}
\label{cccc}

\begin{footnotesize}
\sf
\section{eeee}
\label{fffff}

\#Print Out Time:          3/15/2010 2:06:07 PM                             
  \\ 
\#Ref:                     xyz
..............  

\begin{tabular}{lllrl}
........

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`\nopagebreak`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm#nopagebreak) between your `tabular` and the text?

Comment: You can try wrapping both of them in a `samepage` environment, or if that fails, in a `minipage` environment.

Comment: The `placins` package provides the `\FloatBarrier` command, which could be useful

Answer (score 3):

Well, not knowing some salient variables --- such as (i) the size of the piece of the paper (a4, USletter, ...), (ii) the width and height of the text block on the paper, (iii) the font and font size you're using in the main text area and the tabular block, (iv) the line spacing (e.g., single- or double-spacing), or (v) the number of rows you need to display --- it's not easy to give specific suggestions. If you think it's just a matter of letting a couple of extra lines of text appear on the page in order for both the text and the table to coexist peacefully on the same page, you may want to issue the command

```
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
```

and see what happens. If this doesn't work, you'll probably have to fiddle with the parameters that govern items (ii) through (v) above.