# Continue a sentence without page break

Tags: page-breaking, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Widow *word* on a page? I thought LaTeX wouldn't do that.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/widow-word-on-a-page-i-thought-latex-wouldnt-do-that)
>   [How to eliminate unnecessary page break in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/how-to-eliminate-unnecessary-page-break-in-latex)

I have the following problem: In the end of my document, the last 2 lines appear on an empty new page. However, it looks esthetically ugly, and I would like the 2 lines to continue on the previous page, and end the document with a full page, even with the price of smaller margin or more condensed text. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/widow-word-on-a-page-i-thought-latex-wouldnt-do-that/3130#3130.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enlarge any page by a "single line" using

```
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
```

on that specific page. Two extra lines are obtained by a length of `2\baselineskip`, etc. This will increase the bottom margin to accommodate the addition. There is also a "user friendly wrapper" for this function in the form of the [`addlines` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/addlines).

Comment: The question and the answer are a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26431/how-to-eliminate-unnecessary-page-break-in-latex. We should try and avoid duplicates if possible. They make searching much more difficult.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: That's true - didn't see it in the "Related" posts, and your original suggestion also didn't include it, so I posted.